# Samsung Galaxy S5 AT&T - Stop 5.0 Lollipop update mid-download

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, installation, downloading

I received an alert for a software update the other day that I kept putting off until today. Unbeknownst to me when I started the download, it was Android 5.0 Lollipop. I've read around that it still has some issues that need to be worked out and I'd like to avoid updating until I see better reviews and updates as Kit-Kat is running beautifully.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to stop the download. I've tried restarting my device, looking for an option to stop it, etc. The only thing I've found that works is disabling wi-fi which, while it works, isn't a permanent solution.

Is there a way to stop the download and not install Lollipop?

Answer (score 1):

well let the update download. After downloading you have manually install it so don't install. This way you can prevent the lollipop update and stay on kitkat.